# Why is non-type template parameter expression handling inconsistent across compilers?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, templates

Here is something I observed across various compilers. It seems there are compiler bugs.

```
template <int I>
struct X
{ };

int main(void)
{
  X<(16 > 1)> a;       // Works on vc9, works on g++ 4.1.2, works on Comeau 4.3.10.1
  X<(int(16) > 1)> b;  // Works on vc9, works on g++ 4.1.2, works on Comeau 4.3.10.1
  X<(16 >> 1)> c;      // Works on vc9, works on g++ 4.1.2, works on Comeau 4.3.10.1
  X<(int(16) >> 1)> d; // Fails on vc9, works on g++ 4.1.2, works on Comeau 4.3.10.1

  X<16 > 1> e;         // Fails on vc9, works on g++ 4.1.2, fails on Comeau 4.3.10.1
  X<int(16) > 1> f;    // Fails on vc9, fails on g++ 4.1.2, fails on Comeau 4.3.10.1
  X<16 >> 1> g;        // Fails on vc9, works on g++ 4.1.2, fails on Comeau 4.3.10.1
  X<int(16) >> 1> h;   // Fails on vc9, works on g++ 4.1.2, fails on Comeau 4.3.10.1
 }
```

Why is that inconsistency? What is allowed/disallowed by the standard? Such behavior is also responsible for syntax error while using BOOST_AUTO on vc9. It appears to me that Comeau is doing the right job by rejecting all the expressions without parenthesis.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the template being non-type, but rather because it uses the '>' character inside the template.

Comment: You are right Marcin, I've seen this inconsistent behavior with overloaded '>' and '>>' operators of user-defined classes.

Comment: Because this would be a rarely used construct and thus less likely to be tested for. And you would be mad to use them in real code anyway. But it is worth submitting these as tests to the compiler manufacturer so they can add it to their test suite of mad things people do.

Comment: +1 for the good research. I guess it's not easy to find compilers differ that much only on a single topic :)

Comment: Nice catch. To increase the quality of compilers for everyone, you should submit a GCC bug report and do whatever the equivalent process is for MSVC.

Comment: gcc 4.4.2 seems to have fixed the bug. Its compilation result matches with that of Comeau.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules are as follows for C++03:

> After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a template-name, if this name is followed by a `<`, the `<` is always taken as the beginning of a template-argument-list and never as a name followed by the less-than operator. When parsing a template-id, the first non-nested `>` [foot-note:  A `>` that encloses the type-id of a `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or `const_cast`, or which encloses the template-arguments of a subsequent template-id, is considered nested for the purpose of this description. ] is taken as the end of the template-argument-list rather than a greater-than operator.

So the result is:

```
  X<(16 > 1)> a;       // works
  X<(int(16) > 1)> b;  // works
  X<(16 >> 1)> c;      // works
  X<(int(16) >> 1)> d; // works

  X<16 > 1> e;         // fails
  X<int(16) > 1> f;    // fails
  X<16 >> 1> g;        // works (">>" is not a ">" token)
  X<int(16) >> 1> h;   // works (">>" is not a ">" token).
```

However, in C++0x the following are the rules

> After name lookup (3.4) ﬁnds that a name is a template-name, or that an operator-function-id refers to a set of overloaded functions any member of which is a function template, if this is followed by a `<`, the `<` is always taken as the delimiter of a template-argument-list and never as the less-than operator. When parsing a template-argument-list, the ﬁrst non-nested > [foot-note:  A `>` that encloses the type-id of a `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or `const_cast`, or which encloses the template-arguments of a subsequent template-id, is considered nested for the purpose of this description.] is taken as the ending delimiter rather than a greater-than operator. Similarly, the ﬁrst non-nested `>>` is treated as two consecutive but distinct `>` tokens, the ﬁrst of which is taken as the end of the template-argument-list and completes the template-id.

Result will be

```
  X<(16 > 1)> a;       // works
  X<(int(16) > 1)> b;  // works
  X<(16 >> 1)> c;      // works
  X<(int(16) >> 1)> d; // works

  X<16 > 1> e;         // fails
  X<int(16) > 1> f;    // fails
  X<16 >> 1> g;        // fails (">>" translated to "> >")
  X<int(16) >> 1> h;   // fails (">>" translated to "> >")
```

Be sure to disable C++0x mode in comeau when testing

Comment: Great answer! On Comeau, with C++0x disabled, the result is as described above (6 work, 2 fail).

Comment: You can always count on litb to do the research as well :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Stroustrup](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0201700735/app01lev1sec9): "The first non-nested > terminates a template argument list. If a greater-than is needed, parentheses must be used."

Thus, the compilers that tolerate the second set of expressions do so incorrectly; the compiler that fails on `X<(int(16) >> 1)> d;` is buggy.

Comment: that'd mean compilers that fail on X<16 >> 1> are also buggy, as >> is not two > (famous nested template nuisance)